# Roblox changes font randomly

Tags: lua, key-bindings, roblox

I accidentally started typing and triggered a switch in Roblox fonts. I know it's a keybind. But I forgot what I had pressed.

I was trying to use _G for a global function.

I posted this here because I have no access to Roblox Dev forum.

[See image because I'm new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOKQz.png)

Let me make this clear. If you open a roblox studio script, its font is different. I changed it and want to change it back.

I knew no one could help, that's why I can't do anything.

Comment: I can't make any sense of your post. What fonts are you talking about? we can't read your mind so we don't know what you know or don't know. So you need to share this information with us if you want help.

Comment: I agree with Piglet in this case. Also for the future it helps to put your code in a code block

Comment: Did the font change size? Or was it a completely different font?

Comment: Did you somehow change your system font?

Answer (score 1):

So I take it that your script editor font has changed?

Anyway to fix that

1. Open Studio
2. Click File in the top right
3. Open Settings
4. Find the script editor on the right
5. Once you click on script editor you should find font on the right side
6. The default font for the script editor is Fira Mono

Please tell me if this works or not.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the same problem as mine before. Roblox studio updated the default font to fira mono (I forgot when maybe a long time ago lol) If you are users before the update, the og default font is ***Courier New***. But the main point of the question is how to change fonts so here is the way to do it:

1. open settings(in the file tab)
2. select the script editor setting tab
3. There should be a font configure input list
4. Choose the font you want
5. (Extra) change font size if you want

Hope this helps